# How to take mean of one column while filtering by another column's criteria in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, anaconda

I am working in Python (normally an R guy) and I am trying to create this function for a specific application.  Basically, I am trying to take the mean of the column "CallsPresented" for each month in the "Month_of_Year" column.  I know I am making this more complex than I need to.  How should I accomplish this?

```
def get_monthly_mean(df):
    avg_by_month = []
    months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'June', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    for i in range(11):
        x = np.mean(df['CallsPresented'][df.loc[df['Month_of_Year'] == months[i]]])
        avg_by_month.append(x)
    return months
```

Comment: You're using numpy; please add that tag. It'll help you to get specialists.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Well this is more of a pandas thing tbh. Normally pandas is not tagged with np.

Comment: Also... 'June'?

Comment: Can you please post example data or a sample dataframe? You will get better answers if you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you looking for something like [this](https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/)?

Comment: What happened to `May`?

Comment: @jpp that is it.  I could not find anything there for the life of me.  Thanks

Comment: try: `df.groupby('Month_of_Year')['CallsPresented'].mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `groupBy` the month column and calculate the `mean` for each group?

Something like

```
def get_monthly_mean(df):

    df_grouped = df.groupby('Month_of_Year')['CallsPresented'].mean()

    #Then you can pass the column to a list or just return the grouped df, 
    #whatever suits your use case better

    return df_grouped
```